# Builtin Modules' state in Linux kernel at bootup

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Do Kernel builtin modules need to be loaded using modprobe or they get loaded at boot-up?

Comment: "builtin modules" are not modules, they're parts of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

They are compiled into the kernel binary. The kernel will call their init function during startup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actually i asked this question because i compiled my kernel with I2C as builtin driver then i thought to write my own driver and now i am using it without any problem.How is it possible?Builtin module would have allocate resources for its own use and so do i but without any conflict.

Comment: i2c what? Host bus controller driver? A slave device? If so, you have no conflicts until the existing driver is automatically loaded (via DTS, ACPI, or platform code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I am talking about i2c Driver.I chose it to be built in the Linux kernel during compilation of Linux Source code.And then wrote my own driver.Now i am confused about the state of builtin driver.Is it already loaded automatically after Linux boots or it needs to be mode probe? Because i am able to load my driver without any problem and it seems to me that builtin drivers are also needed to be loaded by the user.